# Image replaced by an iframe when clicked

Tags: html, image, iframe

I'd like to display an image (300x169) and when a user clicks on the image it is replaced (in the same location) with an iframe of the same dimensions.

Comment: It is SO rules that you should show what you have tried.  Not simply ask for a solution to a problem without showing you have done something to try to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Use an onClick event

Answer (score 0):

I only show you the jquery approach:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Some html content</p>
        <div id='holder'><img id='myImg' width='300' height='169' src="noimage.png"></div>
        <p>Some other html content</p>
    </body> 
    <script>
        $('#myImg').click(function () {
            $('#myImg').remove();
            $('<iframe/>')
                .attr('id', 'iframeId')
                .attr('src', 'http://someurl')
                .appendTo("#holder")
        });
    </script>
</html
```

>